# Is it possible to take Differential Backup in Mysql and later restore it with full backup

Tags: database-restore, mysql-backup

I want to take differential backup of a MYSQL DB, this backup should contain the data after the last full backup was taken. and then I should be able to restore both full and latest differential backup.

Ref: Like we do in MSSQL database.

I am able to take full backup with "mysqldump" but not able to find a way to take differential backup

Answer (score 0):

MySQL does not manage incremental backups.

If you really want to do, you need to use another tool, like XtraBackup